# str_replace text with PHP

Tags: php

My users want to be able to have a contact form on their website. Understandable. But it's not really working out.

```
<?php
function ubbreplace($text){
    $text = str_replace("[contact-form]",'<?php include("contactform.php"); ?>',$text);
    return $text;
}
?>
```

The include is not including the contact form. Why is that?

Comment: What is it returning?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Nothing actually, not a single error and I have error reporting currently enabled

Comment: Well, for a start anything inside single quotes will be taken literally.

Comment: So what have you done to debug this?  Identify where the code is failing. Is `str_replace()` finding the needle? Does the file exist?  Is the function even being called?  Do you get any warnings or errors?

Comment: PHP will replace the text and the result with be a text string called `$text`, the PHP *inside* text will never be run, it's just a bunch of characters to the compiler,

Comment: @martin So there's no way around this?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Done pretty much everything you said; no errors or warnings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are approaching the concept entirely from the wrong end, what you are doing is working with strings, and these strings will not be processed by PHP as functions, or includes or other core markup.

you can insert variables into a string but this happens at execution time, and the string will not then be re-executed (and also ignores the fact the include is not a variable at all but is a *language construct*).

So, what can you do about this? Well - rearrange your code with the logic that:

- You have a string you want to find, and then act once it's been found.

So, to do this try this code logic (customise, obviously). You want to find the "flag" you have set and then replace it with a correct marker,

```
<?php
if( stripos($text,"[contact-form]") !== false){
    include("contactform.php");
} 
?>
```

The above will maybe not do exactly as you intend, because its behaviour depends heavily on what is inside the included PHP file.

You will maybe have to rearrange your include contents (you can `return` data from an include if you really need to, but I don't really recommend that).

As a small improvement I would also recommend using `mb_stripos()` function instead of the standard `stripos();`.

So to get a cleaner more usable result, set the contents of the include to a variable such as `$contactForm = "HTML contact form data";` and then always run the include, but only output the contents if the flag is found:

**include contains:**

```
$contactForm = "Some HTML contact data";
```

**parent file contains:**

```
<?php
include("contactform.php");
if( stripos($text,"[contact-form]") !== false){
     print $contactForm;     
} 
?>
```

Or what is very probably easier for you to implement is:

```
<?php
include("contactform.php");
function ubbreplace($text){
    $text = str_replace("[contact-form]",$contactForm,$text);
    return $text;
}
?>
```

[Include in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), Please note references to return values

---

> [Splash58's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37257597/3536236) (and [Brogans Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37258077/3536236)) of using output buffering is also a perfectly
>   good solution and saves a lot of the effort of quantifying included output into
>   varaibles in my answer, although my answer is primarily to explain the
>   purpose and the failings of your original question.
>
> Given a completely open option I would choose to use Output buffering
>   to solve this issue but you do need to know what's going on, so if
>   output buffering is new to you [definitely read up on it](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) first.

Comment: I will start messing around with it and I'll let you know if it worked, thanks

Comment: @J.Doe I have heavily updated my answer, please read over it again and try the newer solution :-)

Comment: The other answers are perfectly fine and great but your answer explains the issue more; for that matter I will accept your answer so if anyone else has a issue like this they can also understand from your answer what is going wrong. The issue is fixed, thank you. :)

Comment: @J.Doe that's awesome, I'm glad it works for you now :-)

Answer (score 2):

The str_replace function that you're using is working as expected. If you don't see anything in your browser, view the source code and you'll see a `<?php` tag within your HTML code.

The output is the stuff that normally goes to your browser. A buffer is a cache of data. Output buffer is a cache of data that would have normally gone to your browser, but didn't because you buffered it instead.

To get your desired results, we need to grab the contents of the contactform.php file and replace [contact-form] with those contents. We can do this by capturing the output from the contactform.php into a variable and using that variable as the replacement.

```
<?php

function ubbreplace($text){
    if(strpos($text, '[contact-form]') !== false) {
        ob_start();
        require 'contactform.php';
        $replace = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        $text = str_replace('[contact-form]', $replace, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}

$content = ubbreplace('Hello world! [contact-form]');
echo $content;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ubbreplace($text){
    if (strpos($text, "[contact-form]") !== false) {
       ob_start();
       include("contactform.php");
       $replace = ob_get_contents();
       ob_end_clean();
       $text = str_replace("[contact-form]", $replace, $text);
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain the output buffering functions, etc.?

Comment: Output buffering captures the data that would otherwise normally flow directly to your browser as a variable.

Comment: ( @Brogan I was hoping for a bit of clarity and explanation from the answerer, code only answers are not usually very useful)

Comment: I will write in hour when Will back to comp. I'm driving now

Comment: @splash58 haha that's a pretty impregnable excuse for not doing it sooner.